# Defining a tensor in terms of its trace and other tensors

Tags: tensors, xact

I'm starting to learn xAct for tensor operations. So I am dealing with 3 tensors: $T_{abc}$, $Q_{abc}$ and a metric tensor $g_{ab}$; with these tensors I have an equation like $$T_{abc} = Q_{abc} + T_a g_{bc} + \cdots.$$ What I would like to do is:

- Take traces of this equation.
- Substitute the equation obtained from tracing back into the main equation.
- Eventually, solve the equation for $T_{abc}$ in terms of its trace $T^k_{ak}$.

For example, let's say my equation is

$$T_{abc} = Q_{abc} + 2 Q^k_{ak} g_{bc}.$$

Taking its $a,c$ trace gives $Q^m_{bm}$ in terms of $T^m_{bm}$:

$$Q^m_{bm} = \tfrac13 T^m_{bm}.$$

Then the main equation becomes

$$T_{abc} = Q_{abc} + \tfrac23T^m_{am}g_{bc}.$$

I tried using `IndexSet[Q[m,-b,-m], T[m,-b,-m]/3]`, but when I put `Q[m,-b,-m]` into my main equation, it complains since I have both $T_{abc}$ and $T^m_{bm}$ now.

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Here is my code, I :

```
In[43]:= << xAct`xTensor`

During evaluation of In[43]:= ------------------------------------------------------------

During evaluation of In[43]:= Package xAct`xTensor`  version 1.2.0, {2021,10,17}

During evaluation of In[43]:= CopyRight (C) 2002-2021, Jose M. Martin-Garcia, under the General Public License.

During evaluation of In[43]:= ------------------------------------------------------------

During evaluation of In[43]:= These packages come with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type Disclaimer[]. This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. See the General Public License for details.

During evaluation of In[43]:= ------------------------------------------------------------

In[44]:= (* Dimension of the manifold *)
DefConstantSymbol[dim];

(* Define manifold M *)
DefManifold[M, dim, {a, b, c, d, m, i, j, k}];

Define tensors 

In[57]:= DefTensor[T[a, -b, -c], M, Antisymmetric[{-b, -c}]] ;

During evaluation of In[57]:= ** DefTensor: Defining tensor T[a,-b,-c]. 

In[58]:= DefTensor[Q[-a, -b, -c], M, Symmetric[{-b, -c}]];

During evaluation of In[58]:= ** DefTensor: Defining tensor Q[-a,-b,-c]. 

In[59]:= DefMetric[-1, g[-a, -b], lc];

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining symmetric metric tensor g[-a,-b]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining antisymmetric tensor epsilong[-a,-b]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefCovD: Defining covariant derivative lc[-a]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining vanishing torsion tensor Torsionlc[a,-b,-c]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining symmetric Christoffel tensor Christoffellc[a,-b,-c]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining Riemann tensor Riemannlc[-a,-b,-c,-d]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining symmetric Ricci tensor Riccilc[-a,-b]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefCovD:  Contractions of Riemann automatically replaced by Ricci.

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining Ricci scalar RicciScalarlc[]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefCovD:  Contractions of Ricci automatically replaced by RicciScalar.

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining symmetric Einstein tensor Einsteinlc[-a,-b]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining Weyl tensor Weyllc[-a,-b,-c,-d]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining symmetric TFRicci tensor TFRiccilc[-a,-b]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining Kretschmann scalar Kretschmannlc[]. 

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefCovD:  Computing RiemannToWeylRules for dim dim

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefCovD:  Computing RicciToTFRicci for dim dim

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefCovD:  Computing RicciToEinsteinRules for dim dim

During evaluation of In[59]:= ** DefTensor: Defining weight +2 density Detg[]. Determinant.

In[62]:= DefTensor[hm[-a, b, c], M, PrintAs -> "\[CapitalDelta]"];

During evaluation of In[62]:= ** DefTensor: Defining tensor hm[-a,b,c]. 

Solving equations 

In[93]:= $PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;

In[78]:= (* Subscript[T, abc] = Subscript[Q, abc] + 2Subscript[Q^k, ak]Subscript[g, \
bc] *)
mainEq = T[-a, -b, -c] - Q[-a, -b, -c] - 2 Q[m, -a, -m] g[-b, -c];

In[79]:= (* Trace mainEq over a,c *)
ContractMetric[mainEq*g[a, c]] // Simplification

Out[79]= - Q[-a, -b, a] - 2  Q[m, -b, -m] + T[-a, -b, a]

- SHOULD SUM - Q[-a,b,a] - 2Q[m,b,-m] !!!

In[96]:= (* Write Subscript[Q, ka]^k in terms of Subscript[T, ka]^k *)
IndexSet[ReplaceDummies[Q[-k, -a, k]], 1/3 ReplaceDummies[T[k, -a, k]]]

During evaluation of In[96]:= Validate::repeated: Found indices with the same name k.

During evaluation of In[96]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[Null] returned to top level.

Out[96]= Hold[Throw[Null]]

- CAN I SOLVE FOR Q[-a,-b,a] DIRECTLY FROM THE TRACE?

In[91]:= (* Substitute Subscript[Q, ab]^a into the equation *)
IndexSet[T[-a, -b, -c], Q[-a, -b, -c] - 2 Q[m, -a, m] g[-b, -c]];

During evaluation of In[91]:= Validate::repeated: Found indices with the same name m.

During evaluation of In[91]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[Null] returned to top level.

Out[91]= Hold[Throw[Null]]

(* Trace Subscript[T, abc] over a,b *)

In[94]:= ContractMetric[T[-a, -b, -c] g[c, b]]

Out[94]= Q[-a, c, -c] + 2/3 dim  T[b, -a, -b]

I NEED TO USE THE SAME EQUATION (mainEq) SEVERAL TIMES BY SUBSTITUTING EACH TIME WHAT I FIND FROM TRACING IT. IS THERE A BETTER WAY TO DEFINE THIS EQUATION THAN USING EXPRESSION ?
```

Comment: Please share complete code for the equations.